# How can I set Maximum value for Htm.Textbox Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code and I want to set Maximum value for TextBox and when user enter a value bigger than max value receive an alert.

<%:Html.TextBox("NumPercoPecal" + item.LkpNamePerfo + "_" + empl.NumPrsnEmply, item.NumScorePerfo, new { id = "NumPercoPecals["+m+"]"})%>

please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256753/min-max-value-validators-in-asp-net-mvc I think it can help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a built-in feature for Html.TextBox about setting the maximum value like maxlength attribute.
But there are many ways for setting the max value of a textbox.

In Asp.Net MVC 2, you can set your Model's attributes.
You can use [Range] attribute for setting the min and max value range for a textbox.