# MVC 3.0 decimal number validation on model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In DB i have decimal type like `decimal(10, 2)`

Can i validate input filed on MVC 3.0 model if is decimal like for URL: [Url] ,...

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/05/new-validation-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc-3-future.aspx

Does anything like this already exist or i must write custom validator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decimal fields are automatically validated by the default model binder. You don't need to do anything special. If you try to assign an invalid value to a decimal field on your view model you will get a validation error.

Comment: Thx. What about the length. 10,3 ?

Comment: @senzacionale, what about it?

Comment: i want that no one can write value larger than 10,3

Comment: @senzacionale, ah, you would use the `[Range(min, max)]` attribute. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256753/min-max-value-validators-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will helps you.... create a custom validator that uses [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) under the covers.

> `^\d*\.?\d+$`

Comment: Don't use regexes for these things. They'll break badly with localization.