# Range limt for Datetime and date field in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I’m using `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue` and `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue` to define the range for Datetime and Date field using following lines of code.

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM", "12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM", ErrorMessage="\'D2\' must be within 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.")]
public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> D2{get;set;}//;
```

But when I entered date `11/08/2016 12:00 am` into textbox it throws an error message

> 'D2' must be within 1/1/1753 12:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59 PM.

So please let me know what wrong in above code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format. you need to setup the datetime variable different, not like the display value

Comment: did you try to use ISO-Format notation (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS). Your format depends on the locale and might create "interesting" behaviour therefore.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IValidatableObject` interface for your class and check date validation there like below

```
public class Sample : IValidatableObject
{
    public DateTime Date { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Date > new DateTime(2012, 12, 12))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("you cant enter it");
        }
    }
}
```