# RangeAttribute for DateTime validation not working in MVC web app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

Using the `RangeAttribute` with a type of `DateTime` to to specify a minimum and maximum value for a date property does not work. A question on how to work around this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21777412/6236042), with the highest-voted solution being:

> There is no need to disable jQuery date validation (and that is likely
>   to cause other issues). You just need to override the range method of
>   the $.validator.
>
> By default, it works with numeric values (and then falls back to a
>   string comparison), so you can add the following script (after
>   jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, but not wrapped
>   in $(document).ready

```
$.validator.methods.range = function(value, element, param) {
    if ($(element).attr('data-val-date')) {
        var min = $(element).attr('data-val-range-min');
        var max = $(element).attr('data-val-range-max');
        var date = new Date(value).getTime();
        var minDate = new Date(min).getTime();
        var maxDate = new Date(max).getTime();
        return this.optional(element) || (date >= minDate && date <= maxDate);
    }
    // use the default method
    return this.optional( element ) || ( value >= param[ 0 ] && value <= param[ 1 ] );
};
```

**Can someone please help me understand how to implement this solution?**
(My HTML & Javascript knowledge is embarrassingly poor, so any help is appreciated.)

---

From the description of the solution, I would assume I want this script to end up at the bottom of the generated HTML, so I have tried  adding it to my `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`, so I now have:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.methods.range = function(value, element, param) {
    if ($(element).attr('data-val-date')) {
        var min = $(element).attr('data-val-range-min');
        var max = $(element).attr('data-val-range-max');
        var date = new Date(value).getTime();
        var minDate = new Date(min).getTime();
        var maxDate = new Date(max).getTime();
        return this.optional(element) || (date >= minDate && date <= maxDate);
    }
    // use the default method
    return this.optional( element ) || ( value >= param[ 0 ] && value <= param[ 1 ] );
};
</script>
```

The script now appears at the bottom of the generated HTML, however it doesnt seem to affect the validation error that appears on the form.

Comment: Did u add the following code in your web.config file?<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>

Comment: do you have it in a `@section Scripts {  <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />  }` block? scripts won't run outside of that...

Comment: @Maddy89 I dont think it should be necesary to create a `web.config` file when working with dotnet core MVC. However, I've added these settings via `appsettings.json`, which hasnt made any difference. I've also set `HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = true` when configuring services. I can tell it's deffo denabled, as setting it to false results in no validation taking client side validation taking place

Comment: @mvermef I have added above code to my `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`, and within my view, I have `@section Scripts { @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");} }`, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The script now appears at the bottom of the generated HTML, however it doesnt seem to affect the validation error that appears on the form.

Based on the code that you provided, I suspect that it might not reach into `if ($(element).attr('data-val-date'))` code block, which casue your customized client-side validation function does not work as expected.

Please check the source code of the corresponding element and make sure it has `data-val-date` attribute.

Besides, if the element does not include `data-val-date="true"` as below, you can modify the code like below to make the code snippet (within if condition block) could be reached while the function is triggered by that specific element.

*StartDateTime property*

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2020", "2/29/2020")]
public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
```

*Html source code of that specific element*

[image]

*Modified code to check if current element is that specific element with `if $(element).attr('id') == "StartDateTime")`*

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script>
    $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {

        //console.log(param);

        if ($(element).attr('id') == "StartDateTime") {
            var min = $(element).attr('data-val-range-min');
            var max = $(element).attr('data-val-range-max');
            var date = new Date(value).getTime();
            var minDate = new Date(min).getTime();
            var maxDate = new Date(max).getTime();
            console.log(minDate + " | " + maxDate + " | " + date);

            return this.optional(element) || (date >= minDate && date <= maxDate);
        }
        // use the default method
        return this.optional(element) || (value >= param[0] && value <= param[1]);
    }
</script>
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely spot on! The statement `if ($(element).attr('data-val-date'))` was never true, as the `data-val-date` attribute did not exist - the attribute was simply called `data-val`. After changing the JS to check for this, and to check the type is date, the validation works as expected. Thanks for your help!